# Using same names for params and variables

Tags: delphi, winapi

Can't find info bout this anywhere on the internet.

I got a list of Pointers. I'm trying to cast from pointer to HWND, which is needed by `GetWIndowText` method

```
    procedure DoSomething
    var
      text: string;
      someArray: array[0..256] of char;
    begin
      text := GetWindowText(HWND(PointerList[i]), someArray, 256);
    end
```

Delphi wont let me compile because 'missing operator or semicolon' - what the...?

I'm trying to declare variable: `var hwnd: HWND;` - Constant or type identifier expected... erm...?

I'm following some code from the internet.

Comment: `var hwnd: HWND;` delphi code is not case sensetive, so your `hwnd` var has the same name as `HWND` type, so it is error. use another var name;

Comment: also, `HWND = LongWord` do you need pointers to integers? I mean, your pointer list has to be integer(HWND) list

Comment: @teran That is not correct. An `HWND` is as wide as a pointer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, in d2010 `HWND` is declared as `LongWord`, in XE2 it has to be `NativeInt`. I wanted to say that, as for me, `PointerList` must be `array of HWND` or `TList<HWND>`, so it is not "pointer" list.

Comment: Do not use codez from internets :-P You've downloaded a syntax error - unterminated procedure declaration.

Comment: @teran, HWND is a particular case of HANDLE, which has to be Pointer-sized.

Comment: @user If an `HWND` really was a `HANDLE` then you would be able to call `CloseHandle` on it. A `HANDLE` has a kernel object behind it whereas a window handle is a user object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the variable declaration the problem is that the variable name and the type are the same. You could solve the problem by qualifying the type:

```
var
  hwnd: Windows.HWND;
```

And you may need to do the same in the cast if your real code has a variable named `hwnd` visible at the point at which you call GetWindowText:

```
text := GetWindowText(Windows.HWND(PointerList[i]), someArray, 256);
```

The issue is that your variable declaration is hiding `Windows.HWND` and replacing it with the variable named `hwnd`.

Perhaps easier would be to avoid the name clash in the first place:

```
var
  WindowHandle: HWND;
...
text := GetWindowText(HWND(PointerList[i]), someArray, 256);
```

Comment: It was a typo in the post, even with the balanced parentheses  it throws the same. Also, when I declared HWND as you adviced and tried hwnd := HWND(PointerList[i]) it throws that Missing operator or semicolon...oh wait....

Comment: Please can you use copy/paste in future so that we see the real code.

Comment: you were right, it was because of parametr and variable name conflict (i'm not using copy paste oly bacause I'm simplyfying the code for the post, and also, original code is not in english )

Comment: I understand that and if you must make modifications I recommend that you do the modifications in the IDE and check that what you are about to post does actually exhibit the problems you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

You can add circumflex accent after a pointer:

```
text := GetWindowText(HWND(PointerList[i]^), someArray, 256);
```

Comment: "circumflex accent" == dereference operator

Comment: It is not an accent, it is an operator. Same as little cross means addition, funny little star means multiplication, ^ means pointer dereference.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand. My English is bad :-(

Answer (score 0):

(*Posting this as an answer because the comment does now allow enough text*)

I think it would be beneficial to point out that the issue here is called SCOPE.

Let's say you have the following code that generates the "Missing operator or semicolon" error:

```
procedure DoSomething(HWND: THandle);
var
  text: string;
  someArray: array[0..256] of char;
begin
  text := GetWindowText(HWND(PointerList[i]), someArray, 256);
end;
```

**As a debugging tip**, If you place your mouse cursor over the HWND in GetWindowText, you'll get a tooltip something like "**Var HWND: Cardinal - Unit1.pas (100)**" 100 being the line number. Basically, the compiler "sees" the function HWND parameter in your function instead of the Windows HWND type in Windows.pas.

Using this technique you can verify exactly what each item (function, type, variable, etc) really points to, *as seen by the compiler*.